# How to compare the data from current cell with its previous cell inside TableView Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a JSON is look some thing like this :

```
"product": [
    {
        "product_id": 471,
        "info": "123456",
    },
    {
        "product_id": 471,
        "info": "356697456",
    },
    {
        "product_id": 472,
        "info": "1432",
    },
    {
        "product_id": 473,
        "info": "4321",
    },
]
```

I want to set my TableView to look something like this image below :

[image]

what I want is:

1. If the first cell in the TableView I want the Product 1 (in Red color) shown.
2. If the second cell's `product_id` is same with it previous cell's `product_id` then Product 1 is no longer shown, it disappears.
3. Since the 3rd cell's `product_id` is not same with previous cell (second cell), so the red label Product 2 is shown up.
4. Same go to `Product 3` and the rest of the cell in the `TableView`

What I already tried:

In order to achieve this,I need to get the indexPath inside `cellAtRow` delegate,so I compare each cell's `product_id` with the previous one,and then control the logic inside.

Here is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell

        let thisIndexPath = indexPath.row
        if thisIndexPath - 1 > -1 {

            let previousProductId = self.productItem[thisIndexPath - 1].productId
            let thisProductId = self.productItem[thisIndexPath].productId

            if  previousProductId == thisProductId {

                cell.productLabel.isHidden = true
                cell.productHeight.constant = 0
                cell.productnameTopContraint.constant = 0
                cell.productnameBottomContraints.constant = 0
            }else {
                cell.productnameLabel.isHidden = false

            }
        }else{
            cell.productnameLabel.isHidden = false
        }

        cell.item = selfProductItem[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

But now the problem is:

-- When the `TableView` first launch,the UI display like that I shown above,but when I start scrolling,all the cell's *Product* label(in red color) is gone,although the `product_id` is not same with the previous cell's `product_id`.

-- When I scroll back to the first cell,the Product Label(In red color) is gone as well.Which means the UI is only right at first launch of the screen,which is not persistent.

So my question is:

1. What is the correct way to compare data from current cell to the previous cell?
2. Is it right to do the comparison inside `cellForRowAt` delegate method?If not,where should I do this?

Comment: It looks like you are using 1 section, try to create sections per product_id and add row to to section for the same products.

Comment: @TomaszCzyżak hey bro,cause the `product 1` or `product_2` will appear in the bottom also

Comment: try setting the height constraints in else part too

Comment: @TomaszCzyżak the data is not section by section,is product 1,2,3,1,2,1 ,the sequence is totally random

Comment: @hardikparmar else part means which part?

Comment: `else` part of this : `if  previousProductId == thisProductId {` and this : `if thisIndexPath - 1 > -1 {`

Comment: just filter out the datasource after parsing the json... Solving logical issue on stack where you only display data is nonsense...

Comment: @hardikparmar bro u are right..is solved! Can you make an answer?so I can accept it

Comment: @DominikBucher do you mind to make an answer? So I can learn..I really like to know

Comment: @ken Look at Josh's answer, almost exactly what I wanted to tell you... Please keep in mind you should fix the source of issue, not symptoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that to solve your issue, you should think about how you will store your JSON data.

You could begin by creating a `struct` called 'Product' which will store the product information and then by making it `Equatable` you can add a function which will allow you to compare the productID's:

```
/// Structure Of A Product
struct Product: Equatable{

  var productID: Int
  var productInfo: Int

  static func == (lhs: Product, rhs: Product) -> Bool {
    return lhs.productID == rhs.productID
  }
}
```

Now to use this your structure you can create an Array variable to store your Products:

```
//Array To Store Array Of Product
var products = [Product]()
```

In this example I am just manually inputting the product information but you should handle this in a better way. However, it does illustrate  one way you could 'start' to handle this:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //1. Create Products
    let productOne = Product(productID: 471, productInfo: 123456)
    let productTwo = Product(productID: 471, productInfo: 356697456)
    let productThree = Product(productID: 472, productInfo: 1432)
    let productFour = Product(productID: 473, productInfo: 4321)

    //2. Add Them To The Products Array
    addUnique(productOne)
    addUnique(productTwo)
    addUnique(productThree)
    addUnique(productFour)

}

/// Checks That A Product Doesn't Exist
///
/// - Parameter product: Product
func addUnique(_ product: Product) {
    if !products.contains(product) {
        products.append(product)
    }
}
```

In Step 1 we are manually creating the products.

In Step 2 we are calling the addUnique(_ product) function which will only allow unique Products to be stored.

After ensuring that there are no duplicate ProductID's, it should be easy for you to set the format as you like:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    cell.productLabel.text = products[indexPath.row].productID
    cell.productnameLabel.text = products[indexPath.row].productInfo
}
```

Of course you will need to fix any colouring of labels etc.

Comment: This should be accepted answer since it goes logically - dividing dataSource from the presenter and is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I tried and it is working fine. I make one dummy array for you. Please check bellow

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tblProduct: UITableView!

var arrProduct = NSMutableArray()
var arrForSection = NSMutableArray()
var arrForProductId = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
    dict.setValue("471", forKey: "product_id")
    dict.setValue("123456", forKey: "info")
    arrProduct.add(dict)

    let dict1 = NSMutableDictionary()
    dict1.setValue("471", forKey: "product_id")
    dict1.setValue("356697456", forKey: "info")
    arrProduct.add(dict1)

    let dict2 = NSMutableDictionary()
    dict2.setValue("472", forKey: "product_id")
    dict2.setValue("1432", forKey: "info")
    arrProduct.add(dict2)

    let dict3 = NSMutableDictionary()
    dict3.setValue("472", forKey: "product_id")
    dict3.setValue("4321", forKey: "info")
    arrProduct.add(dict3)

    print(arrProduct)

    self.createSection()
}

//MARK:
//MARK: Create section
func createSection()
{
    arrForSection.removeAllObjects()
    let arrtemp = NSMutableArray()

    arrtemp.addObjects(from: (self.arrProduct as NSArray) as! [Any])

    for i in 0 ..< arrtemp.count
    {
        let dict = self.arrProduct[i] as! NSMutableDictionary
        let strProductId = (dict["product_id"] as? String)!

        if(!arrForProductId .contains(strProductId))
        {
            arrForProductId.add(strProductId)
        }
    }

    for j in 0 ..< arrForProductId.count
    {
        let strTempDate:String = arrForProductId .object(at: j) as! String
        let arr1 = NSMutableArray()

        for i in 0 ..< arrtemp.count
        {
            let dict = arrtemp .object(at: i) as! NSMutableDictionary
            let strProductId = (dict["product_id"] as? String)!
            if(strProductId == strTempDate)
            {
                arr1.add(dict)
            }
        }
        arrForSection.add(arr1)
    }

    self.tblProduct.reloadData()
}

//MARK:
//MARK: TableView Delegate
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return self.arrForSection.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return (((arrForSection .object(at: section)) as! NSMutableArray).count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tblProduct.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!

    let dictData = ((arrForSection .object(at: indexPath.section)) as! NSMutableArray).object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary

    cell.textLabel?.text = dictData["info"] as? String

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
{
    return arrForProductId[section] as? String
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Result see attach

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you can divide cells of your table view in sections and assign header (name of product) to each section. Please rever to [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the height constraints in else part too.
`else` part of this : `if previousProductId == thisProductId {` and this : `if thisIndexPath - 1 > -1 {`.